# Is there a way to toggle coc's linting?

Tags: plugin-coc

I'd like to be able to turn it off when starting a new project and turn it back on when I have written more code.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Have you checked `:help coc` (or whatever the relevant section is)? Also, sometimes the project community (eg, on GitHub) has answers to questions about the project.

Comment: This looks relevant: https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/blob/99188750671907ab091e68eebc90ec906088a51d/doc/coc.txt#L2023

Answer (score 5):

Based on [`:help coc`](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/blob/99188750671907ab091e68eebc90ec906088a51d/doc/coc.txt#L2023), I would use `:CocDisable` and `:CocEnable`.

If you can find a way to detect if coc is enabled (`b:coc_enabled` I think was mentioned in the documentation and looks helpful), you could write a smarter “toggle” command.

Answer (score 1):

I add the same which and based on the answer of Ben Knoble I wrote:

```
function! CocToggle()
    if g:coc_enabled
        CocDisable
    else
        CocEnable
    endif
endfunction
command! CocToggle :call CocToggle()
```

It provide the CocToggle command that call either CocDisable or CocEnable depending if Coc is enabled or not.

Comment: This did not work for me. Another answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64507845/how-to-toggle-vimplug-plugins-on-and-off-on-the-fly

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Is the other answer working for you?